# How to iterate the following list and print its elements?

Tags: java

I want to create a list for the class. When I try to iterate through the array list, it doesn't print the elements of the list.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{
    int N;
    String s;
}
public class Main {
    public static List <Test> itr=new ArrayList<Test> ();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.N=i;
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                t.s="Even";
            }
            else
            {
                t.s="Odd";
            }
        }
        for(Test t:itr)
        {
            System.out.println(t.N+" "+t.s);
        }
    }
}
```

It should print its position and its status showing whether it is odd or even.

Comment: as you are not adding to your `itr` list it will be empty.  Check out the javadocs

Comment: `itr.add(t);` in the last line of your first for-loop

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Scary, you need to add elements to `itr` list. Also you may want to declare `int i` in loop itself.

```
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.N=i;
        if(i%2==0)
            t.s="Even";
        else
            t.s="Odd";
        itr.add(t);
    }
    for(Test t:itr)
        System.out.println(t.N+" "+t.s);
```